# excluded_categories not working with get_next_post()

Tags: wordpress

I am using following code to create a link to next post, here `$hidden_categories` is an array containing IDs of categories i want to exclude from next link.

```
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post(false, implode (", ", $hidden_categories));
if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But its not excluding posts from categories that i want to exclude. Is there anything wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hidden_categories_array = implode("," , $hidden_categories);
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( false, $hidden_categories_array, true);
if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```